# Is it normal that the editor says "the referee report is for editor's eye only so I cannot share it with you"?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, editors

I recently receive an editorial letter that is unwilling to share referee reports. The letter explicitly mentions the existence of such report but the editor don't want to send it to me.

Is not sending referees reports normal and happen frequently?

Related: [How to interpret this rejection email from Journal of American Math Society? Anything to read between the lines?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122823/how-to-interpret-this-rejection-email-from-journal-of-american-math-society-any)

---

I decided to accept the second answer, though all answers are very good. The editor told me that the referee is unwilling to share his report. This is exactly the case suggested by the David's answer.

Comment: What are you looking for that isn't already explained in the question you link to?

Comment: The editor's answer may be unpleasant, but it does not seem unclear. What is your question?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Contrary to other opinions here, in my experience as an author, reviewer and editor it is entirely normal to receive referee reports that should not be shared with the author. This is an action taken by the referee and not the editor normally. Some reasons why referees don't want the text of their opinion shared with the authors.

1. They know the author well and their identity would definitely become obvious should the report be shared.
2. The report contains technical details that impact on the paper, so need to be in the report, but would definitely break anonymity if shared, because it would allow the author to immediately work out the referee.
3. The referee is unsure about whether they are correct in what they are saying. They might say something like "I think this might have been done before, but I'm not sure where. Try X, they are likely to know for sure."
4. The report is very short, and the referee simply doesn't think it's particularly useful to give the author. This is particularly true of quick opinions, which many journals in mathematics try to obtain before a full referee's report, which can take a long time.
5. The referee wrote a report, and it contains personal details about somebody -- the author, referee, or a third party -- that they think would be inappropriate to be shared with the author.
6. The referee clicked the wrong box in the form.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your field and how common is it not to receive referee reports?  In my area (pure math), I'd say it happens from time to time, and it is more common for weak papers, but even in the case of initial rejections (no request for revisions), you get back referee reports/quick opinions most the time.

Comment: Kind of agree with most of your points but 5. Why would he referee share personal details in the report? 3. Why would the referee use something unsure to decide the future of a paper?

Comment: @Kimball Algebra. I'm saying what I saw coming in as an editor, because obviously I cannot say whether there were such reports as an author. I have needed to make some reports unavailable to the author as a referee for various reasons, but these were quick opinions rather than full reports. There's no obvious point to making a full report unavailable to the authors.

Comment: @dodo I mean that if there is anything 'unprofessional' in the report, the referee will flag it as not for author consumption. Suppose I write a report that says that the results are fine, not particularly interesting but good enough, but I'm worried about X, and you should check with John Smith about that, as it could collapse the whole thing'. I'm not going to make that report available to authors. Then John Smith gets back and says that X is fine, but he doesn't think the paper is that good, just in an e-mail rather than a report (this happens very often)...

Comment: Now the editor has enough to reject the paper, but no report to give the author. He either rejects, or tries to convince either me or John Smith to write a second report to hand to the authors. You have to understand that editors are grateful if any referee responds, so bothering them again is not an option.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Seems like editing is not an easy task, even if the editor is famous and established. Finding and commanding referee could be difficult

Comment: @dodo to answer your question about 5, at least in my field things are quite close knit. Often, the editor knows the referee and author personally. If I have sent a paper to be evaluated by X, and I sent one a few months before for another quick opinion by X, the referee's report might make a comparison between the two. "This paper is much better than the one you sent me before by Y, so if you accepted that you should definitely accept this." No way can I send that to the author, but it's a very useful report for the editor.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Ok I think I understand: so X is a referee and you are the editor. You two have been evaluating two versions of the same paper in two different submissions. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @dodo No, I mean that the editor might send two different papers to the same referee over the space of a few months, and the referee might reply that the newer paper is better than the previous one they were sent.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I am not sure I fully understand. Are those two papers on the very similar topic? If not I am not sure if such direct comparison is always rigorous.

Comment: @dodo So what if it isn't rigorous? Referees' opinions are just personal opinions. There is no objective standard for a paper. I'm asking someone their opinion of how good a paper is. They will definitely make comparisons to other people's work.

Answer (score 38):

In my experience, the web sites for sending in referee reports often have spaces for two reports, one for the author (and editor) and one for only the editor. I've often left the second space blank, so that all my comments could (and presumably would) be forwarded to the author. But it's entirely possible for a referee to put almost nothing in the first space and put almost all comments in the second space. (I wrote "almost" because the web site software often requires you to put something in the first space, but it can't detect that your something is worthless.) In such a case, the editor could make a decision but couldn't forward anything useful to the author. (Of course, the editor could also look for a new referee.)

Comment: That's a nice description, but it's not an answer to the OP's question: is it normal not to get a review, and implicitly, what is the possible *reason* for not getting a review.

Comment: @Dilworth - I would imagine that a comment about the paper being effectively gibberish/plagiarised/valueless would be something you'd share with the editor but not the author. I'm not saying that's what's happened here, but those are examples

Answer (score 18):

As far as I'm aware of, this is highly **not** normal. Peer review in journals normally means that you get to see the review as an author. Any other decision may show some lack of trust between the editor and the author. For example,

1. the editor thinks the author is a "crank";
2. or does not deserve a serious treatment;
3. or that the specific paper submitted was clearly below the acceptance threshold of that journal so that a serious review was not even conducted (in this case there is a "review" containing one or two paragraphs, stating the paper is clearly below the bar). This case is called "desk reject".

Comment: There may be a distinction between a "referee report" and a review. Authors typically see reviewer comments on their manuscript; they may not see referee comments that the editor uses to make a decision, such as a decision to accept or reject the manuscript. As mentioned in the Q&A that OP linked to, this may happen when reviewers are asked not to review a paper but to decide whether they think it is worth reviewing.

Comment: Correct. But the OP claims that there "is a referee report". So as I've mentioned now in my answer, there may be a one-two paragraphs stating that the paper is below the bar. This is however not really a referee report.

Comment: It's not clear what the editor is calling a "referee report".

Comment: Cases where the report could identify the reviewer might also qualify here?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent, I don't think so. In this case the Editor can simply amend the review or ask the reviewer to amend it.

Comment: @Dilworth Where possible, sure, but sometimes it's not simple to obfuscate the reviewer's identity without also obfuscating the issue they've raised. Especially an issue in niche fields where the pool of potential reviewers may be very small, and well known to the author - from there, knowledge like "only one of those people is knowledgeable enough about $SUBTOPIC to raise this objection" can be enough for identification.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent it gets more interesting if it's so specific that the knowledge that a referee not being able to share details already gives information on who the referee might be :) (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcdI20liY50&ab_channel=StudioC) for a humorous example)

Comment: *Peer review in journals means that you get to see the review as an author* This is surely not the case. You get a decision, not necessarily a review (e.g. if the manuscript is desk rejected).

Comment: @Allure but a desk-rejected manuscript hasn't been peer-reviewed.

Comment: @Allure, correct. That's what I said. To clarify I added the word "normally" now, thanks.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime it has, it's just that the reviewer is the editor.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely **not normal**. It implies something went wrong. One possible explanation is that the reviewer wrote something highly confidential and the editor isn't sharing it. Alternatively, the reviewer wrote something really bad (e.g. rude/abusive/sexist/irrelevant) and the editor isn't sharing it.

Still, when that happens (I've seen it as an editor), the more common thing to do is to just not tell the authors of the existence of the confidential review, which avoids the authors asking questions like this one.